# Horizontal alignment with colorbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, threeparttable, colorbox

I am getting quite frustrated trying to center a three-part table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor,siunitx}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption[Table]{Text\tnote{a}.}\label{table1}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \colorbox{lightgray}{% for grey shade
        \begin{tabular}{l l l}
            \hline \hline
            \vspace{-0,2cm}&&\\
            \textbf{1st Column} & \textbf{2nd Column} & \textbf{3rd Column} \\ \midrule
            test\tnote{\textdagger}   &                     &                      \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }\endgroup % for grey shade
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[\textdagger] test
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I tried several times putting it in a center-environment, tried out several times with \centering, but nothing worked. Apparently, the problem is with

```
\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
```

Has anyone a solution? I would greatly appreciate any help.

The table looks like:
[image]

Comment: If you want your table to be horizontally centered why do you use `threeparttable`'s option `flushleft`?

Comment: I must have overlooked the flushleft option, thanks! If I then put the center environment before the threepart table, it works! However, the table notes are then out of place...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Your use of the flushleft option was correct: it is the tables notes only which are flushleft. It seems there is an incompatibility of this option with the use of `\colorbox`

Comment: Dear Bernard, thanks for your comment, as well as your solution posted below which works perfectly, I thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a work-around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}%
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable, caption, cellspace, hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering\captionsetup{skip = 4pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption[Table]{Text\tnote{a}.}\label{table1}
\rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{lightgray}
 \begin{tabular}{Cl l l}
            \toprule\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\midrule[0.5ex]\arrayrulecolor{black} \midrule
            \textbf{1st Column} & \textbf{2nd Column} & \textbf{3rd Column} \\ \midrule
            test\tnote{\textdagger} & & \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[\textdagger] test
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-around; put the `colorbox` inside an extra `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor,siunitx}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]\centering
\caption[Table]{Text\tnote{a}.}\label{table1}
\begin{threeparttable}\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}%
    \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%    <-----
    \colorbox{lightgray}{% for grey shade
        \begin{tabular}{l l l}
            \hline \hline
            \vspace{-0,2cm}&&\\
            \textbf{1st Column} & \textbf{2nd Column} & \textbf{3rd Column} \\ \midrule
            test\tnote{\textdagger}   &                     &                      \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
    }\endgroup % for grey shade
    \end{tabular}                       %    <-----
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[\textdagger] test
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution, your solution actually works perfectly fine !! Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is another work-around using a `parbox` to enclose the `tablenotes` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor,siunitx}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption[Table]{Text\tnote{a}.}\label{table1}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \colorbox{lightgray}{% for grey shade
        \begin{tabular}{l l l}
            \hline \hline
            \vspace{-0,2cm}&&\\
            \textbf{1st Column} & \textbf{2nd Column} & \textbf{3rd Column} \\ \midrule
            test\tnote{\textdagger}   &                     &                      \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }\endgroup % for grey shade

    \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
     \item[\textdagger] test
    \end{tablenotes}}
\end{threeparttable}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]